# EF Core disable model checking

Tags: entity-framework-core

After we ported our code to EF Core / ASP.Net Core I'm looking for a way to prevent checking the database with the model.

We used to do it like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

But that doesn't work anymore, what's the new version of doing this?

Comment: I think the "new way" is simply to remove that code.

Comment: Then how do I disable checking the model?

Comment: I don't think it's checked. EF Core supports only explicit migrations.

Comment: Will check when I get migrations running again.. Thanks!

Comment: @Lonefish did you ever solve this? EFCore still checks the schema as soon as you query the DB for the first time.

Comment: We don't have that issue, it just doesn't check it. (Noticed it a few minutes ago again). Unless you query the table the change is in it doesn't check it.